# New tag: verb position

Tags: discussion

I think there should be a tag such as verb-position. The three positions of the German verb, normal position, end-position and front-position, raise many questions. And the tag verb is too vague.

Answer (score 5):

We should not create too many sub-tags for special case in case we already have a generic tag. Too many tags for sub-topics may not be helpful either for searches, or for people who subscribe a given tag (which was the major intent of the tag system).

Already existing generic tags for questions on word-order in a sentence including verb positions would be:

- [sentence-structure](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure)
- [word-order](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order)

If needed we can also combine any of these tags with another tag. Questions on the word order of a verb should then get the following tags:

- [verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs)[word-order](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order)

As both cover more or less the same questions we may consider to create a tag synonym to one of these. I am all open to suggestions, especially as to which of both tags should be the master tag but I do not recommend to create another tag that would include questions that could easily be tagged with an already existing tag.

Comment: Moreover, these tags can be combined with [[tag:verb]], i.e., a question that is especially about positioning the verb should be tagged with [word-order] and [verb].